# Cannot insert data into mbf database

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sqlconnection

I have been trying to insert data into a sql database for the last hours. for one or other reason I am able to connect to the database, but no data is inserted into the database. if I run the sql statement directly in the database it does seem to work. So therefore, I was able to conclude that the statement is correct. Furthermore, there were no errors in runtime. I have got the following c# code:

```
//Neither of these statements seem to work.
string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO dbo.eventTable (colA, colB, colC, colD, colE, colF, colG, colH, colI) VALUES (@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f,@g,@h,@i)";
string altSqlStatement = "INSERT INTO dbo.eventTable (colA, colB, colC, colD, colE, colF, colG, colH, colI) VALUES (@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f,@g,@h,@i)";

    foreach (DataRow row in importData.Rows)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(form1.Properties.Settings.Default.showConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand())
            {
                insertCommand.Connection = conn;
                insertCommand.CommandText = sqlStatement;
                insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", row["CUE"].ToString());
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", row["HH"].ToString());
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", row["MM"].ToString());
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", row["SS"].ToString());
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", row["FF"].ToString());
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", row["ADDR"].ToString());
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g", row["Event Description"].ToString());
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@h", row["CAL"].ToString());
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i", row["PFT"].ToString());

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    int _affected = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch(SqlException e)
                {
                    // do something with the exception

                }
            }
        }
   }
```

if I change the connection parameters to something false, an error occurs, so that seems correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Alex

Comment: Three things to try (probably wont solve anything, but just to narrow it down):  1.  Try instantiating your `SqlCommand` directly with connection/commandtext like `using(SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlStatment, conn))`  2.  Check to make sure all your columns in the database are of type `varchar` or `char`, you are casting all the parameters to `string` so you may have some conflicts there.  3.  Debug and check the results of `insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` by watching the `_affected` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this function as a template, big difference is that it is opening the connection before creating the command. I've not seen it done the way you have it setup. You also really should be opening the connection outside of the for loop, not in the for loop. Why open and close it repeatedly; the foreach should be inside the inner 'using'

```
public void ExecuteQuery(string query, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = query;

        if (parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (string parameter in parameters.Keys)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter, parameters[parameter]);
            }
        }

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
}
```